# How to use standardSQL in bigquery via R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I want to execute `bigquery` using standardSQL via R.

```
library(bigrquery)
sql = paste("#StandardSQL\n SELECT SUM(copies) ",
            " FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents` ",
            " WHERE NOT binary", sep="")

# Execute the query and store the result
sample_contents <- query_exec(sql, project = "###", useLegacySql = NULL)
```

But I got below errors:

`ERROR: Query text specifies use_legacy_sql:false, while API options specify:true`

I couldn't find where to set API option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `useLegacySql = NULL`, specify `false`. You can track the request to change the default dialect for bigrquery in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/147). In the meantime, you will need to set the appropriate value for `useLegacySql`.